# Adding mobile to Facebook account - no sms

Tags: facebook, mobile, sms

I am trying to verify my mobile number for facebook developers. It kept failing with my mobile number and now says: "Sorry, we have already tried texting multiple codes and they all seem to have failed. Please click here to get help."

I found out after that I had mobile texting turned off in my fb settings (it does this automatically). I'm guessing this is why it didnt work.

but now, even though I have turned it on, I get the same error message each time:
"Sorry, we have already tried texting multiple codes and they all seem to have failed. Please click here to get help."

Please help

Comment: perhaps let the cool down period go?patience?Go to fb official help forum.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the other option that 'Call me ' and  I received a  call from Facebook, that was an Recorded speech that gave me four digit code. All work now.

Regards